# duplicate entry android support v4 in serviceinfoversion impl.class

Tags: java, android, gradlew

i have this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.class
```

on this build.gradle app :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mtma.mytripmyadventure"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

i have try many things to do but the result still the same

i have add  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

but still error

help me to resolve this.. icant resolve it in 1 day
thx stackoverflow

Comment: Do you have any jar files within the libs folder?

Comment: You also can remove **both** lines of `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4`

Comment: theres no file in libs folder .. how should i do sir ..

Comment: My second comment? What happens when you remove them?

Comment: when i remove  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

this error still disturb me
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.class

Comment: please help up this question ... :)

Comment: There is no need to comment "please help" when I'm already trying to... And I said remove both of them. The one that also has `force = true;`

Comment: one of my activity need it .. so when i remove both of them my application is work .. buy when im going to activity which needs android support the error going to like this :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mtma.mytripmyadventure/com.mtma.mytripmyadventure.activity.UserProfileActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error in your latest comment is completely different as it relates to an XML issue in your Activity.

You do not need the support-v4 dependency explicitly. It is included with the v7 dependency. That being said, definitely do not need to `force = true`  on it

The solution to the first error is remove both dependencies  of `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4`

Comment: You are welcome to use a Collapsing toolbar, but you'd have to ask another question and include the XML layout for that activity if you want that fixed

Comment: can i ask here with my collapsing toolbar ?

Comment: Not here on this post, no, but you can [ask as many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as the site allows

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, I was importing

`compile fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1'`

and had to add "@aar" termination

`compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'`

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me.

```
compile('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
}
```