# Duplicate entry erro duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy.class

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, navigation-drawer

My app was working fine and i was able to release APK. But when i added the latest Google play service library: **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'**. then it starts showing this error during Relasing signed APK.

**Error:**
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy.class

my build.gradle are:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cricket.livematch"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName = "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

}
 lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false

}
 }
```

**dependencies**
{

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
        compile 'com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog:cfalertdialog:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
```

}

Comment: Check for duplicate libraries in gradle and why are you using compile instead of implementation

Comment: see this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320795/duplicate-entry-android-support-v4-in-serviceinfoversion-impl-class

Comment: @UsamaAltaf i can release apk if i remove the Google play service library but when i add it then it gives that error

Comment: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0 check if this library works maybe the issue in 19.5.0